# How many partitions of what sizes should I make for a dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I'll be getting a laptop soon. It only has 500 gigs. Windows is for gaming and Ubuntu for fun stuff.

1. Should I go 150:350gigs, or 200:300?
2. Do I make 4 partitions (os+data) for each os, or do I just flop windows on one partition?

2.a Is it customary on Linux to have two partitions?

3. Should I make the Ubuntu partitions when creating Windows, or should I make 1 or 2 partitions for Windows, and let the rest be unallocated space, and then the Ubuntu installer will recognize that and let me format it?
4. How can I prevent windows from accessing my Ubuntu drives, while ubuntu being able to access windows? The goal is that windows doesn't steal my data.
5. Do I need to worry about the UEFI thingie?

Comment: Multiple questions, and unclear exactly what you're asking, but they've been asked before: Depending on which is installed first https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi or https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu For preventing Windows reading your Ubuntu drives, I don't think win can read ext filesystems by default, so it shouldn't automatically read anything, or you can encrypt your Ubuntu home or whole install, I'm fairly sure you click the "encrypt" checkbox(es) when installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you want to game on the laptop I would recommend 250:250. Ubuntu is typically a lighter weight system and won't need a ton of space.
2. I would install windows first on the entire disk. Then partition 250 G as unalocated space. Through the disk manager. Then install Ubuntu on that space from an installation media. This is called a dual boot.
3. You can encrypt your install of Ubuntu when installing it.

Comment: is it customary to have a designated OS partition, and a "data" partition in ubuntu like it is customary in windows (C: D:)? Should i give windows 2 partitions or throw everything to one?

Should I worry about the uefi thingie? That guide was made in 2012, and im sure the new ubuntus have no problems getting installed to dual boot in win 8.1. 

Thanks!

Comment: No you do not need to have additional data partitions. If your worried about space for data I recommend getting an external hard drive that can be used regardless of the OS.  Regarding UEFI, you will need to enable legacy boot and disable secure boot from the bios.

Comment: Don't forget to mark questions as answered if it is to your satisfaction.